# How can I extract distances measured in different units from a string?

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector containing data describing distances except the units are mixed between meters and feet, and occasionally contains both units separated using a variety of different delimiters.  What I want to do is extract the value and convert it into meters.  For example, if the element of the vector is "100 m" then I want to extract it as "100", and if it's "600 Feet" then extract it to "182.4".  The approach I'm am considering is identifying all elements of the vector that contain a "m" or " m" and just extracting the numerical values in those cases.  If it contains "feet" or any of a number of other versions of that, extract the number and convert it to meters.  It's less clear what I shoulddo when it comes presented in a string like  "137 m (Outdoors); 46 m (Indoors)", or "Up to 450 ft / 137 m Outdoors; Up to 150 ft / 46 m Indoors".  An ideal solution would be to grab the distance in meters then and exclude the other values.

In those cases, I think it would be useful to try and come up with a regex expression to grab the digits immediately preceding the specified unit, but I'm struggling with this.  So far the method I'm trying to use to accomplish this is piecemeal- first grab the elements that meet the "m" criteria, then " m", etc; but I expect there's an easier way to do this with regex, but I don't know how to do that.  If anyone could provide some suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.  The data is pasted below.

```
c("", "100 m", "", "", "200 m", "", "", "1000 m", "1400 m", "1400 m", 
"", "", "0", "230 m", "", "", "", "106.7 m", "", "", "", "300 m", 
"300 m", "250 m", "250 m", "250 m", "", "", "", "656 feet", "", 
"", "600 Feet", "", "500 Feet", "", "600 Feet", "180.8 m", "152.4 m", 
"Not Applicable", "152 m", "500 Feet", "228.6 m", "228.6 m", 
"228.6 m", "152 m", "152 m", "152 m", "152.4 m", "", "152.4 m", 
"152.4 m", "600 Feet", "137.2 m", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"304.8 m", "304.8 m", "304.8 m", "600 Feet", "400 Feet", "228.6 m", 
"228.6 m", "Up to 590 ft", "200 m", "300 m", "100 m", "Not Applicable", 
"228.6 m", "182.88 m", "182.88 m", "250 m", "750", "250", "150 m", 
"", "", "304.8 m", "152.4 m", "228.6 m", "152.4 m", "228.6 m", 
"228.6 m", "228.6 m", "138 m", "150 m", "", "", "", "228.6 m", 
"228.6 m", "", "228.6 m", "Not Applicable", "Not Applicable", 
"228.6 m", "137 m (Outdoors); 46 m (Indoors)", "Up to 450 ft / 137 m Outdoors; Up to 150 ft / 46 m Indoors", 
"150 m", "", "304 m", "100 m", "", "150 m", "137.2 m", "300 m", 
"182.9 m", "", "183 m", "300 m", "Up to 1000 ft", "600-feet / 182.88 m ", 
"400 ft; 121.92 m", "150 m", "300m", "300m", "", "300m", "300m", 
"", "300m", "", "300m", "300 m", "50 m", "250", "250", "250", 
"250", "250 m", "250 m", "200 m", "Not Applicable", "118 m", 
"50 m", "50 m", "304.8", "300 m", "244 m", "244 m", "244 m", 
"198.1 m", "198.1 m", "600-feet/182.88m", "600-feet/182.88m", 
"", "182.9 m", "182.9 m", "182.9 m", "182.9 m", "300 m", "180 m", 
"152.4 m", "182.9 m", "", "", "30.5 m", "30.5 m", "30.5 m", "304.8 m", 
"304.8 m", "304.8 m", "300 m", "50-300 meters", "50 - 300 m", 
"50-300 meters", "50-300 meters", "50-300 meters", "", "300 m", 
"158.5 m", "", "274.3 m", "", "", "182.9 m", "182.9 m", "300 m", 
"", "", "300 m", "", "300 m", "152.4 m", "200 m", "300 m", "152.4 m", 
"152.4 m", "152.4 m", "", "300 m", "300 m", "", "", "", "")
```

Comment: When you say "it's less clear what I should do", it kind of makes it impossible to answer the question. We don't know what the goal is, and we can't guess.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I"ll modify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `stringr` package,

`stringr::str_extract(x, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=\\s+m|\\s+(f|F)eet|\\s+ft)")`

`(?=)` stands for preceded by. The rest of it is using OR statements to find the differing types.

Comment: your solution doesn't extract the feet and doesn't convert it either

Comment: That's true, but it's still a massive help and I can figure it out the rest of it.  I'm going to accept the answer and when I figure out the last little bit I'll post a comment here.

Comment: @denis The question asked for the digits. `str_extract(x, "m|\\sm|(f|F)eet|ft")` will give the units that you can use for conversion.

Comment: @troh I know. I don't know if it is my computer,  but it didn't extract the digits when it was feet (see line 30 for example).

Comment: The updated query now extracts feet, but it doesn't seem to work for meters any longer.  
> stringr::str_extract("500 feet", "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=\\+sm|\\s+(f|F)eet|\\s+ft)")
[1] "500"

but
> stringr::str_extract("500 m", "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=\\+sm|\\s+(f|F)eet|\\s+ft)")
[1] NA

Comment: @BradDavis typo for `\\s+m`. Its looking for one or more spaces now before m

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for your help, and thank you for explaining how it works. :)